# Blender 2.8 Reference images in local view

Tags: modeling

Is there any way to make reference images show up in local view?  They seem to disappear.  I used Shift-A/Image/Reference to create it.  Is there something I'm not seeing?  Or perhaps that feature is not available in 2.8? Reference photo would be soo hand in local view!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you selecting both the reference image and the meshes before entering local view? For example:

Entering local view only with the cube and then entering while also having the reference image selected

[image]

Comment: Oh I did not think of that!  I suppose I am used to 2.79 still! Thanks for the simple solution! Sometimes it's too easy it's hard LoL!

Comment: @Skelkeys don't worry! I'm still getting used to 2.8 as well, it's so beautiful yet so different hahaha