# Reference image workflow with local view in 2.8?

Tags: workflow

I am aware that reference images are now empties and must be selected to be brought along into local view ([Blender 2.8 Reference images in local view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128849/599)).

However, I've set up my scene so that reference images are in a separate collection for easy toggling on/off. I've also disabled selection on this collection, as otherwise I accidentally click and select them from time to time. This means I must:

1. Re-enable selection of reference images in the outliner
2. Select the reference image(s) I want
3. Enter local view
4. Re-disable selection

Every time I toggle into local view. Surely there's a better way to do things?

Comment: One thing that used to work before 2.8 was to hide the Collection (Group) the images were in before entering *Local View*. If you then unhid the group after entering *Local View* they would be visible without all the select-deselect shenanigans. Not sure if this still works for 2.8